# Hacer funcionar trigger (Sql) para multiples campos

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de ventas para sitios de comidas con c# y SQL. He creado un trigger que disminuye el stock cuando se agrega un producto a la venta.
Cada producto (plato) está relacionado con una tabla que guarda los ingredientes y cantidad de ellos que se necesita.

Mi problema está en que un plato lleva varios ingredientes, y estoy consultando por una forma de que el trigger disminuya el stock de todos los ingredientes y no sólo de uno.

El stock se  disminuye de una tabla llamada `insumos`, la cual tiene almacenado cada insumo:

- Id,
- stock,
- stock minimo.

La tabla que almacena los ingredientes se llama `detalle_Plato` y relaciona el Id de cada Plato con el id del insumo y la cantidad de éste que se utiliza.

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[Stock_D_Venta]
on [dbo].[Detalles_Venta]
after insert 
as
declare @Idinsumo int
select @Idinsumo = Dp.Idinsumo from Detalles_Plato as Dp inner join  
Detalles_Venta as Dv on Dp.IdPlato=Dv.Idproducto
declare @Numero_articulos int
select @Numero_articulos =Cantidad from inserted
declare @Cantidad_Insumo decimal (18,1)
select @Cantidad_Insumo =  Dp.Cantidad from Detalles_Plato as Dp inner join    
Detalles_Venta as Dv on Dp.IdPlato=Dv.Idproducto
declare @Gasto_Stock decimal (18,1)
set @Gasto_Stock=@Cantidad_Insumo*@Numero_articulos
update Insumos set Stock=Stock-@Gasto_Stock
where Idinsumo=@Idinsumo
```

Comment: Hola @Andres. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! Para obtener respuestas de calidad, te recomiendo agregar mayor información. ¿Cuál es el DBMS? ¿Cuál es la estructura de las tablas? ¿Cómo están almacenados los ingredientes? ¿De donde debería restarlos? Encontrarás el enlace a [edit] debajo de tu pregunta

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la sugerencia, ya he agregado Mas informacion al respecto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hubiera sido mejor si describieras más explícitamente las diferentes tablas y sus relaciones. Pero creo que pude entender mas o menos.

Lo correcto en este caso es de combinarlo todo en una sentencia, y no es tan difícil. Asumiendo que entendí las relaciones correctamente, el trigger se vería así:

```
alter trigger [dbo].[Stock_D_Venta]
on [dbo].[Detalles_Venta]
after insert 
as
  set nocount on;

  update i
     set i.stock -= t.cantidad
    from insumos i
    join (select dp.idinsumo, cantidad = sum(dv.cantidad * dp.cantidad)
            from inserted dv
            join detalles_plato dp
              on dp.idplato = dv.idproducto
           group by dp.idinsumo) t
      on t.idinsumo = i.idinsumo;
go
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/DBLLW21232)</kbd>

Comment: Hola, he probado el código pero SQL me regresa un error diciendo que un subquery retorna mas de un valor y no es permitido

Comment: Hola Andres. Como no describistes completamente las columnas, tablas, datos, claves foráneas, etc.. yo tuve que asumir algunas cosas.  Si sigues el enlace `Demo` en mi respuesta, puedes ver la estructura de datos que asumí.  Si deseas más ayuda, puedes hacer 1 de 3 cosas, en orden de ideal a menos ideal: Edita tu pregunta para incluir 1) un enlace como el mío que incluye una muestra de los datos para probar en vivo, o 2) una descripción más completa de tus estructuras de tablas y relaciones + datos de prueba, o...

Comment: 3) al menos dime en que se diferencia la estructura + datos de las tablas en mi enlace de la estructura + datos de tu tabla.  Porque como puedes ver en el `demo`, allí funciona bien.  Es más, por el error que recibistes, me suena como que no copiastes bien el SQL.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda  sstan, revisando me di cuenta que era un problema con otro trigger y no con tu codigo.